# How can I redirect /path/variables/ to rewrite to /index.php/path/variables/ in Apache 2.4?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, virtualhost, apache2.4

I recently upgraded my local development server from Apache 2.2 to Apache 2.4 (via Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite). Localhost resolves as expected but the following virtual host settings no longer work (returns `Not Found - The requested URL /subdir was not found on this server.`).

Can you please help me upgrade the following from Apache 2.2 to Apache 2.4?

The goal is to redirect all directories to root using PATH variables. For example: redirect `/abc/def/` to `/index.php/abc/def/`. Index alone works fine. But `/abc/` or `/abc/def/` (or any subdirectory (path) no longer work.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mylocalsite.local
    ServerAlias www.mylocalsite.local mylocalsite_alt.local

    <Directory /Users/my_username/Sites/mylocalsite/html>
        AllowOverride none
        Options all
        Require all granted
        Deny from none

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On

            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

            # Redirect all /img/abc to /img/index.php/abc
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteRule ^img/(.*) img/index.php/$1 [L]

            # redirect all directories to root using PATH variables
            # Ex. /abc/def/ redirects to /index.php/abc/def/
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    DocumentRoot /Users/my_username/Sites/mylocalsite/html
</VirtualHost>
```

Can you see why this is not resolving correctly?

Other debugging:

```
> ping mylocalsite.local
PING mylocalsite.local (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.115 ms
^C
--- mylocalsite.local ping statistics ---
1 packet transmitted, 1 packet received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.115/0.115/0.115/0.000 ms

> sudo apachectl configtest
Syntax OK

> httpd -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server sandbox (/private/etc/apache2/vhosts/virtual_hosts.conf:8)
     port 80 namevhost sandbox (/private/etc/apache2/vhosts/virtual_hosts.conf:8)
             alias sandbox
     port 80 namevhost mylocalsite.local (/private/etc/apache2/vhosts/virtual_hosts.conf:20)
             alias www.mylocalsite.local
             alias mylocalsite_alt.local
ServerRoot: "/usr"
Main DocumentRoot: "/Users/my_username/Sites"
Main ErrorLog: "/private/var/log/apache2/error_log"
Mutex default: dir="/private/var/run/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
PidFile: "/private/var/run/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="_www" id=70 not_used
Group: name="_www" id=70 not_used
```

Comment: If you enter `domain.com/index.php/abc/def/` in your browser does it open right page?

Comment: @anubhava, no. It returns `Not Found - The requested URL /subdir was not found on this server.` Updated the question to reflect this more clearly.

Comment: create a file called `info.php` with this code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then open `http://domain.com/info.php` to check what is its `DOCUMENT_ROOT` value.

Comment: Change the "[L]" to something else. I think L means Last of the rule it may conflict with the following rules since they are the same. Try to change and troubleshoot. It may or may not be the case.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. It turns out I was missing the `mod_rewrite.so` module. Obvious, I know. Points to the first person who posts this: `LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so`

Comment: Glad it worked out, You can post it as answer to your question if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the following lines are uncommented in your `httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
LoadModule alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_vhost_alias.so
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

# restart apache
```